# Getting values in Dropdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using an API to get data from a mySQL database in a JSON format and I show the data in a datatable. What I am doing is to edit something I am showing a modal with the data to edit. It has a dropdown as well. I am confused as I don't know how to populate them with the values from database, I have tried everything till now but still I am not successful.

Here's the script,

```
$('#company .edit-company').live('click', function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#company-label').html('Edit ');
                    $('#company-form')[0].reset();
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '/index.php/company/profile_data',
                        type : 'POST',
                        data : 'companies[]=' + id,
                        beforeSend : function() {
                            $('#loading-span7').show();

                        },
                        success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

                            var details = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log(details.aaData[0].homepage_url);
                            $('input[name=company-name]').val(details.aaData[0].name);
                            $('input[name=package-id]').html(details.aaData[0].package_id);
                            //$('#package-id').val(details.aaData[0].package_id);
                            $('#edit_company').modal('show');
                            $('#loading-span7').fadeOut();
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //alert('error');
                        }
                    });

                });
```

And here's the HTML

```
<div id="edit_company" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×
            </button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel"><span id="company-label"></span>Company</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="company-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…" name="company-name">
                    <label>Package</label>
                    <select name="package" name="package-id" id="package-id">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>

                </fieldset>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                Close
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                Save changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select#package-id option').text(details.aaData[0].package_id);
```

to create options:

```
var option1 = $('<option />', {text: details.aaData[0].package_id}),
    option2 = $('<option />', {text: details.aaData[1].package_id}),
    option3 = $('<option />', {text: details.aaData[2].package_id});

$('select#package-id').append(option1, option2, option3);
```

Comment: You only have one option, are you trying to insert more, and if so with what values ?

Comment: I have different package ids in the database, I want to be able to change the package id.

Comment: I surely don't get it, are you trying to populate the options in that select element, or change an ID ?

Comment: I am populating the drop down with package ids and if a user wants to change the package id, he could change it.

Comment: One more, the values in modal are just filled by only the first item in Database, What can I use instead of aaData[0]?

Comment: That's hard for me to say, as it depends on your object. Try using chrome or firefox, open up the console (F12) and do `console.log(details)` to see your object and what data is available in it, and that's about the best advice I can give ?

Comment: it says details is undefined. :/

Comment: You have to place the console.log inside the success function, same place as you are using the details variable.